# quicksort recursive function with pivot as first element in list does not sort

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, quicksort

My code for the quicksort algorithm is based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort:

```
def partition(L, left, right):
    pivotIndex = left
    pivotValue = L[left]

    for i in range(left,right+1):

        if L[i] < pivotValue:
            L.insert(0, L.pop(i))
            pivotIndex += 1

    return pivotIndex

def _quicksort(data,left,right):

    if left < right:
        p = partition(data, left, right)

        _quicksort(data, left, p-1) # sorting of the left side of the subarrays
        _quicksort(data, p+1, right) # sorting of the right side of the subarrays

def quicksort(data):

    L = list(data)
    left = 0
    right = len(L)-1

    return _quicksort(L, left, right)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    L = [3,4,5,2,3,5,5,2,1,7,2]
    print quicksort(L)
```

It seems to work fine for the first round of partition(), but when the left side is sorted out it changes the pivotIndex so it starts with the wrong index for the sorting of the right subarray. Any suggestions how to make this code?

Comment: `print quicksort(L)`??

Comment: `L.insert(0, L.pop(i))` - technically, this is not QS anymore. this should be an O(1) operation, not O(n).